# Is it possible to send a hyperlink through WhatsApp?

Tags: android, kotlin, text, hyperlink, whatsapp

I am developing an application that sends a message and a link through WhatsApp. To make the appearance more aesthetic, the people behind the application want to send a link within the text in the form of a hyperlink.
Is this possible??

Currently, I am sending an invitation to the client to join the WhatsApp group:

```
private fun shareWhatsAppGroup(mobileNumber: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

        val groupUri = sharedPreferences.getString(
            "my_string",
            "https://chat.whatsapp.com/group_link"
        )
        var messageOne = "Rooster Gallery welcomes you "
        var messageTwo = "Please join our WhatsApp group"
        var messageThree = "By clicking on the following link:"
        var message = messageOne + "\n" + messageTwo + "\n" + messageThree + "\n" + "$groupUri"
        intent.data =
            Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+962$mobileNumber&text=$message ")
        //intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        startActivity(intent)
        if (!isAccessibilityOn(this, WhatsappAccessibilityService::class.java)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact don't have whatsapp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS)
            this.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just encode the message for proper URL formatting. Then whatsapp will detect that this is a link.

```
var message = "$messageOne\n$messageTwo\n$messageThree\n$groupUri"
val encodedMessage = URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")
intent.data = Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+962$mobileNumber&text=$encodedMessage")
```

Comment: I don't have any problem sending a link, my problem I want the link to be hyperlinked to a word so when the client click on it it will open that link, sorry for being late 

Comment: WhatsApp does not support hyperlinks. It does recognize raw URLs [How to link to WhatsApp from a different app](https://faq.whatsapp.com/425247423114725)

Comment: no problem, thank you so much